# Problems creating users in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating the traditional register of users with Laravel and I have a problem to send specific value.

```
public function postUserRegister(){

    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
     );

    $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if($v->passes() ) {
        $user = User::create(Input::all());

    } else { 
        Session::flash('msg', 'The information is wrong');
        return Redirect::back();        
    }

}
```

This code works correctly , but I need to send always the same value into table users and this column doesn't appear in the form. How can I send the value of the table if the value doesn't appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just supply the value manually. There are several ways to do this, here is one:

```
$user = new User(Input::all());
$user->yourcolumn = $yourdata;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input merge to add extra fields.

```
Input::merge(array('val_key' => $val_name));
$input = Input::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think it would be ideal to clean a bit the method, something like that:

```
public function postUserRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        Session::flash('msg', 'The information is wrong');
    }

    User::create($request->all());

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

And now you can simply assign a data to a specific column by using:

```
$request->merge(['column_name' => 'data']);
```

The data can be null, or variable etc. And now the whole code would look something like:

```
public function postUserRegister(Request $request)
{
    $request->merge(['column_name' => 'data']);

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        Session::flash('msg', 'The information is wrong');
    }

    User::create($request->all());

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever data you want directly into the `create` method:

```php
public function postUserRegister()
{
    $input = request()->all();

    if (validator($input, ['name' => 'required'])->fails()) {
        return back()->with('msg', 'The information is wrong');        
    }

    $user = User::create($input + ['custom' => 'data']);

    //
}
```

P.S. Merging that data into the request itself is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the User model by adding the boot() method.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($user) {
            $user->newColumn = 'some-value';
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events